# Jqgrid - Fetch total number of selected rows using Select All

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Select All input checkbox using `multiselect: true`, generates below

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id="cb_grid" role="checkbox">
```

To fetch the total number of rows selected

```
var totalRows = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
console.log(totalRows.length);
```

The snippet gives correct count of total rows selected individually, but if all rows are selected using `Select all` checkbox, it gives incorrect 
count adding `1` to the total number of rows.

How could I avoid this ?

Comment: This is because it is counting `select all` checkbox with total number of rows. Hence total rows + 1 is the count.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar and how could I prevent counting `select all` row so that I gives me correct count ?

Comment: **Which fork of jqGrid and in which version of jqGrid you use in your tests?**

Comment: @Oleg the version is `jqGrid  4.6.0`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. the `length` or `selarrrow` array is correct in my tests. You should provide the demo which reproduces your problem.

Comment: If you use `multiselect:true`, you will have a `Select all` option. When user clicks on it, it will select all the row count including the `Select all` checkbox row, adding `+1` to total number of actual rows selcted

Comment: I did the same, but I get correct number of items in `selarrrow` array.

Comment: Could you pls share fiddle link if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : check for status of select all checkbox and substract 1 from `totalRows.length` if it is checked.

```
var totalRows = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
var totalRowsCount = totalRows.length;
//check if select all checkbox checked then substract 1
if(jQuery('#cb_grid').is(':checked'))
{
    totalRowsCount = totalRowsCount - 1;
}
console.log(totalRowsCount);
```